# Find the ratio of the areas of the circular regions below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Calculate the ratio of the areas of the circular regions below, knowing that the measurement of the ATB arc plus the measurement of the APB arc equals 450 degrees. (answer:$\frac{1}{2}$)

[image]

I try

$\alpha + \theta = 450^o \\
360^o -\alpha + 360^o -\theta + \angle A + \angle B = 360^o\\
720^o -(\alpha+\beta)+\angle A + \angle B = 360^o \implies 720^o -450^o +\angle A + \angle B = 360^o  \\ \therefore \angle A + \angle B = 90^o $

[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be done without more (or any) information on the radii...

Comment: @H.sapiensrex FYI, the original diagram indicates that the circle containing $P$ goes through the center of the circle containing $T$. This, as I explain in my answer, provides sufficient information about the relative size of the radii to show  the ratio of the smaller circle area to that of the larger circle area is the stated answer of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan true. But I had it hammered into me that in questions of geometry, a diagram may be as inaccurate as anything else and shouldn't be relied on for information, particularly with regards to magnitudes. As stuffy as it is, this does seem like a sensible proscription to me, so I commented on that basis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem does not explicitly state an important detail (although its diagram does indicate it, as I explain below), and it's also somewhat poorly worded. Nonetheless, using the values in your diagram, note the original diagram shows the circle containing $P$, with center $O$ and, say, radius $r_1$, goes through the center of the circle containing $T$ (this comes from the dotted line, indicating the radius, going from the first to the second circle), with center $C$ and, say, radius $r_2$.

Joining $O$ to $C$, then since $r_1 = \lvert OA\rvert = \lvert OB\rvert$ and $r_2 = \lvert CA\rvert = \lvert CB\rvert$, we get by SSS that

$$\triangle OAC \cong \triangle OBC$$

Using this and your result of $\measuredangle A + \measuredangle B = 90^{\circ}$, then

$$\measuredangle A = \measuredangle B = 45^{\circ}$$

Since $\lvert OA\rvert = \lvert OC\rvert$, this means $\triangle OAC$ is isosceles. Thus, we have

$$\measuredangle AOC = \measuredangle BOC = 90^{\circ}$$

This matches what's suggested in the original diagram, i.e., that $AOB$ is a straight line. In addition, we also get from $\triangle OAC$ being a right-angled triangle that

$$\lvert CA\rvert = \sqrt{2}\,\lvert AO\rvert \;\;\to\;\; r_2 = \sqrt{2}\,r_1$$

Thus, the ratio of the circle areas (that the question calls "circular regions", and which I initially interpreted as meaning some portion(s) of the circles, e.g., the different shaded regions), of the smaller circle to the larger one (the question also doesn't specify this order, but it's implicit based on the stated answer), is

$$\frac{\pi\,r_1^2}{\pi\,r_2^2} = \frac{r_1^2}{(\sqrt{2}\,r_1)^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks my friend...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: The statement does not seem to be correct, you need more restrictions, for example $R=2r$, where R and r are the radii of big and small circles respectively.

Comment: Thanks for help